# Список контактов в Android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Как можно получить список контактов в ОС Android? Допустим, необходимо получить список контактов в виде пар `<Номер_Телефона; Имя_Контакта>`. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я, всё прочитав, так и не понял, как получить список контактов. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример готового кода.

Comment: В Cursor contacts - все контакты, остается ковырять его и вытягивать нужные поля.

Comment: Ну это понятно. А пример???

Comment: Пример как вытянуть из курсора данные? Это несерьезно... )) У меня есть под рукой, но там много лишнего, если никто не кинет, завтра почищу и кину.

Comment: Очень много лишнего???? Может я смогу разобраться!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Using the Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html)

Во-первых, нужно добавить разрешения `READ_CONTACTS` в манифест.

```
<activity android:permission="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" ... />
```

Во-вторых, нужно запросить список (упрощенно):

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: мурмур, спасибо за ответ. Что ж, имя контакта я получил. Но, похоже, в таблице "contacts" номер телефона не хранится. Довольно хитро устроенная схема БД у Android. Никто не подскажет, как же достучаться до номера телефона этого контакта? Положим, я теперь знаю его _id из таблицы "contacts".

Comment: Вроде бы сам разобрался. При помощи этого:
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/130148/#habracut
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868487/how-to-fetch-contact-number-in-android

Comment: Ссылка, указанная в самом начале ответа - не рабочая

Answer (score 3):

Мой пример реализации, работает весьма шустро и не делает кучу запросов за телефонами для каждого конкретного контакта

```
private static final String CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
private static final String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
private static final String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
private static final String PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
private static final String PHONE_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;

public static ArrayList<Contact> getAll(Context context) {
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

Cursor pCur = cr.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{PHONE_NUMBER, PHONE_CONTACT_ID},
        null,
        null,
        null
);
if(pCur != null){
    if(pCur.getCount() > 0) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> phones = new HashMap<>();
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
            Integer contactId = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(PHONE_CONTACT_ID));
            ArrayList<String> curPhones = new ArrayList<>();
            if (phones.containsKey(contactId)) {
                curPhones = phones.get(contactId);
            }
            curPhones.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(PHONE_CONTACT_ID)));
            phones.put(contactId, curPhones);
        }
        Cursor cur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{CONTACT_ID, DISPLAY_NAME, HAS_PHONE_NUMBER},
                HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0",
                null,
                DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        if (cur != null) {
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    int id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_ID));
                    if(phones.containsKey(id)) {
                        Contact con = new Contact();
                        con.setMyId(id);
                        con.setName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME)));
                        con.setPhone(TextUtils.join(",", phones.get(id).toArray()));
                        contacts.add(con);
                    }
                }
                return contacts;
            }
            cur.close();
        }
    }
    pCur.close();
}
return null;
}
```

Простейшая реализация класса `Contact`

```
public class Contact{
    private String _name = "";
    private String _phone = "";
    private int _my_id;

    public void setName(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        _phone = phone;
    }

    public void setMyId(int my_id) {
        _my_id = my_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Никита Лещёв, спасибо за вашу реализацию - она очень помогла. Правда, вместо номера телефона, выводился id, поэтому пришлось немного доработать. Вот доработанный вариант:

Вместо

```
while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
    Integer contactId = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(PHONE_CONTACT_ID));
    ArrayList<String> curPhones = new ArrayList<>();
    if (phones.containsKey(contactId)) {
        curPhones = phones.get(contactId);
    }
    curPhones.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(PHONE_CONTACT_ID)));
    phones.put(contactId, curPhones);
}
```

использовал

```
while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
    Integer contactId = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(PHONE_CONTACT_ID));

    ArrayList<String> curPhones = new ArrayList<>();

    if (phones.containsKey(contactId)) {
        curPhones = phones.get(contactId);

    }
    curPhones.add(pCur.getString(0));

    phones.put(contactId, curPhones);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

как-то так

```
@Override
    public ArrayList<Contact> getAll(Context context)
    {
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts=new ArrayList<Contact>();
        Contact contact;
        Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                contact=new Contact();
                final String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contact.setId(id);
                String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contact.setContactName(name);
                if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Contact name=" + name + ", Id=" + id);
                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur=context.getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id},
                            null);
                    while(pCur.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String phone=pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        String label= HelpUtils.getPhoneLabel(context, pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)),
                                pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL)));
                        PhoneNumber phoneNumber=new PhoneNumber();
                        phoneNumber.setPhoneNumber(phone);
                        phoneNumber.setType(label);
                        contact.addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                        Log.i(TAG, "phone=" + phone);
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                    contacts.add(contact);
                }
            }
        }
        return contacts;
    }
```